# Relative path using west

Tags: git, zephyr-rtos

Using git, you have the ability in .gitmodules to set an url using relative path
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/NLnZ3.png)

```
62 url = https://github.com/NXP/plug-and-tru
61 branch = int/CHIPSE_Release
62 platforms = ki
63 [submodule "third_party/openthread/ot-nxp" 
64 path = third_party/openthread/ot-nxp
65 url= ../ot-mp.git
66 [submodule "third_party/openthread/ot-qorvo"]
```

Which means that the remote path used is the same as the parent remote repo.

Is there a way to do this using west?